# Twisted client memory leak

Tags: python, twisted

I have an Twisted client app that makes hundreds of connections per minute. I discover that I have a memory leak un my app and I'm almost sure that is related to the ClientFactory() derived class that is never deleted.

I reproduce the problem with a modification of Echo client example from Twisted documentation:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, ClientFactory
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.task import LoopingCall

from sys import stdout

class Echo(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        print 'MADE'
        self.transport.write('XXXX')

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print 'RECV', data
        self.transport.loseConnection()

    def __del__(self):
        print 'DEL PROTOCOL'

class EchoClientFactory(ClientFactory):
    def startedConnecting(self, connector):
        print 'Started to connect.'

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        print 'Connected.'
        return Echo()

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print 'Lost connection.  Reason:', reason

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print 'Connection failed. Reason:', reason

    def __del__(self):
        print 'DEL FACTORY'

def connector():
    print 'CONNECTOR'
    factory = EchoClientFactory()
    reactor.connectTCP('localhost', 7, factory)

#reactor.callLater(2, connector)
register_loop = LoopingCall(connector)
register_loop.start(1)

reactor.run()
```

With this code I discover that the instances of EchoClientFactory() are only deleted when the program shutdowns. They are not deleted when the connections finish. I haven't found in the documentation if I need to do some to get factory instances deleted.

Comment: Does you original implementation also overwrite __del__() methods? If so, you should ask yourself why you need to do this. 99% of the cases its a bad idea. 
I had lots of problems with memleaks in my twisted app, I find objgraph library very helpful to track them down.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `__del__` methods to the protocol and the factory makes them uncollectable.  See the `gc.garbage` list.  This list will be forever growing in this example.  If you remove the `__del__` methods, the problem will go away.  On my 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04 machine, resident memory usage of this client is stable at 13MB.